# Current Node.js download, but node 0.10.13 only. How to install Gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to install a few tools while working trough *Laravel 5.1 Beauty* by Chuck Heintzelmann.

After installing Node.js using the latest MSI (version 4.0.0) for Windows 7, I tried installing Gulp:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

This doesn't work:

```
npm WARN engine get-stdin@5.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"} (current: {"node":"v.0.10.13","npm":"1.3.2"})
```

It seems my version of node is outdated, but I just installed it this morning. The command `npm cache clean` won't help. What else can I do?

Thanks
Pida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I installed *node-v0.12.7-x86.msi* from this directory:

```
https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v0.12.x/
```

Now I've got node 0.12.7. Hiren S.'s answer pointed me to the */download* directory. The installer I had downloaded first was from */dist*.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly compile from the source and use latest nodejs.

if you want latest node.js 4.0.0 then replace ver=4.0.0 and follow the steps.

```
ver=0.12.7 #Replace this with the latest version available
wget -c https://nodejs.org/dist/v$ver/node-v$ver.tar.gz #This is to download the source code.
tar -xzf node-v$ver.tar.gz
cd node-v$ver
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: Based on OS, Steps can be different. Visit here : https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installation

Comment: Thanks, but luckily I found another solution. I can't verify your answer would have worked. Compiling from source on a Windows machine involves *a lot* of steps.